# question about a special case of an $n$ sided polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons

Here is an interesting question that I have been thinking about for awhile now but do not know the answer to.

Suppose you have a convex polygon with $n$ sides. What would be an example of such a polygon s.t. if you randomly picked three sides of the polygon, they could not form a triangle? I am talking about an $n$ sides polygon not some polygon with sides like $5$ or $10$. Just $n$ sides.

Comment: It seems offhand that one could have a quadrilateral with side lengths $1,2,4,8$, which would satisfy the desiderata for $n=4$.  Maybe a similar idea can be made to work for $n>4$.

Comment: @MJD: those won't form a quadrilateral, as $8 \gt 1+2+4$.  You need the sides to grow more slowly.  But $1,2,4,7$ or $1,2,4,6$ would work.

Comment: Right, thanks! ${}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most polygons that people draw will have all the sides about the same length, and any set of three sides can form a triangle. I think it is more interesting to ask what polygons have some set of three sides that cannot form a triangle.

One kind that has a set that cannot form a triangle is a single long side, say $10$ units long, with lots of $1$ unit sides to connect the ends.  If your group of three has the long side in it, you can't form a triangle.  You can also have some number of long sides (of differing lengths) connected by lots of short sides.  Then if you take two longs and a short you also can't get a triangle.

Added, you can make a quadrilateral, even a trapezoid, with sides $3,1,2,1$ where no three sides will form a triangle.  Then a pentagon $5,3,1,2,1$ and generally an $n-$gon with the Fibonacci series.

If the sides are $s_i$ with $s_i\le s_{i+1}$, we need $s_{j-2}+s_{j-1} \le s_j \lt \sum_{k=1}^{j-1}s_k$  You can pick $s_1,s_2$ as you wish (and might as well scale to make $s_1=1$), then respect the left inequality for $s_3$, then get polygons of arbitrary size by successively picking the sides.  Once you get started, there will always be room for the next side.

Added again:  For a geometric series, you need $1+r \le r^2$, which says $r \ge \phi$  In fact you can use $\phi^n$, which is just about the Fibonacci series.  Then you need $r^n\lt \frac {r^n-1}{r-1}$.  This seems to be most trying at $n=3$, restricting us to $r \lt  \frac 13 (1+(19-3 \sqrt{33})^{1/3}+(19+3 \sqrt{33})^{1/3}) \approx 1.839286$ as found by [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%3D%28x%5E3-1%29%2F%28x-1%29).  I checked it in Excel and it works at $1.83928$

Comment: Right but if you randomly choose three short sides then it doesn't work. It has to be such a polygon where any three sides you pick can't be the sides of a triangle :)

Comment: Thats interesting. Question what does the series look like for the Fibonacci series? In terms of a sum

Comment: If you mean what is the sum of $n$ terms, it is $F_{n+2}-1$ as given in [OEIS A000071](http://oeis.org/A000071)

Comment: One more comment and I think I will be good. Sorry if it seems like I am going off on a tangent here but Fibonacci series does work. That is a fact. Heres another interesting question. Would it be possible to have the conditions as I stated in my question except the series is geometric? In other words the sides of the polygon would in fact converge representing them as a series.